# Reply via git send-email to Mailing List Linux

Tags: git, git-send-email

Currently, I have patches that are posted to the mailing list by git send-email.
I received a review of the maintainer, developers.
And now, I want to comment, ex: say thank you, explain ...

How can I execute them via git send-email
Although I have tried with git send-email -in-reply-to, the command seems to be incorrect

Can someone help me correct command?

Example:

When I comments/reply on the patch 
https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10584893/

id-Msg 4f401a77-ae41-5a6e-3e10-51dad300e183@cogentembedded.com

I use

git send-email --in-reply-to=4f401a77-ae41-5a6e-3e10-51dad300e183@cogentembedded.com

With  contained the file with
From: Hoan Nguyen An 
Subject: Re: clk: renesas: r8a77970: add SD0H/SD0 clocks for SDHI

I can not succeed.

Thank You for reading.

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to Stackoverflow :) Could you provide examples of commands you tried and describe the error you got ?

Comment: [`git send-email --in-reply-to`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email#git-send-email---in-reply-toltidentifiergt) (double dashes).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Example I want add comment to https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10584893/. I used following  git send-email --in-reply-to=4f401a77-ae41-5a6e-3e10-51dad300e183@cogentembedded.com </path/to/msg>

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example you can edit as per your requirement:

```
git send-email --cc-cmd=<'./scripts/get_maintainer.pl -norolestats Mypatch.patch'>  --cc xyx@gmail.com --in-reply-to  4f401a77-ae41-5a6e-3e10-51dad300e183@cogentembedded.com --annotate message_file.txt
```

Edit above command by changing strings in between <> brackets as per your requirement. remove brackets<> while executing command, keep your edited strings only.